# Translating Array Declaration from VB.Net to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to translate an array declaration from VB.Net to C#, and I'm struggling. The Vb code is in the format:

```
dim variableName() as typeName = {}
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: This guy is new, so cut him some slack.  Please comment and let him know why you are down voting his question.  People don't learn to be better citizens if they don't know what they did wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
typeName[] variableName = {};
```

For example:

```
string[] names = { "Fred", "Bill", "Jon" };
```

Or using `var` and an explicitly typed array creation expression:

```
var names = new string[] { "Fred", "Bill", "Jon" };
```

Or using `var` and an implicitly typed array (not so good for an empty array, of course):

```
var names = new[] { "Fred", "Bill", "Jon" };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
TypeName[] variableName = new TypeName[] { };
```

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry, I edited a wrong answer :( I did a rollback... The site lists answers at random, and all six look very similar.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Was a bit confused there for a second, but since it wasn't a harmful edit I wasn't motivated enough to rollback.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent C# code would be:

```
var variableName = new typeName[0];
```

... or:

```
var variableName = new typeName[] {};
```

In either case, you're creating a new empty array.